# Zend_Db_Table subquery

Tags: php, zend-framework, subquery, zend-db-table

I have a some SQL that I want to use with ZendFW, but I can't get it working and it's driving me crazy. I get the correct result with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.festival_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m 
WHERE e.status = 1 
AND e.festival_id 
NOT IN (SELECT m.entry_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m WHERE m.entry_id = e.festival_id)
```

Help would be appreciated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 11):

Goran's answer is the best answer. But if you want a zend_db_table style query, this would be an alternative:

```
$sql = $table->select()
          ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
          ->from('entries', new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT festival'))
          ->where('status = ?', 1)
          ->where('festival_id NOT IN (?)',new Zend_Db_Expr("SELECT m.entry_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m WHERE m.entry_id = e.festival_id"));
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure that Zend_Db_Table is capable of handling subqueries.

Why do you need to use Zend_Db_Table?

You can execute the query directly using Zend_Db::query().

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT e.festival_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m 
    WHERE e.status = 1 
    AND e.festival_id 
    NOT IN (SELECT m.entry_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m WHERE m.entry_id = e.festival_id)
");
```

Comment: It can handle subqueires in the params of a fetch. But for what he's trying to do using the db adapter is the right approach.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this works:

```
$subselect = $db->select()
  ->from(array('u1' => 'users'), 'departmentId')
  ->joinInner(array('d' => 'demand'), 'u1.userId = d.adminId', null)
  ->where('d.demandId = ?', $demand->getId());

$select2 = $db->select()
  ->from(array('u' => 'users'))
  ->where('u.departmentId = ?', $subselect);
```

The result was this:

```
SELECT `u`.* FROM `users` AS `u` WHERE u.departmentId = (SELECT `u1`.`departmentId` FROM `users` AS `u1` INNER JOIN `demand` AS `d` ON u1.userId = d.adminId WHERE d.demandId = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also try you sql.This is my code.

```
$select = $db->select()
      ->from(array('e' => ' entries'), array('festival_id'))
      ->distinct(true)
      ->where('e.status =?', 1)
      ->where('e.festival_id NOT IN (SELECT m.entry_id FROM entries AS e, mail_log as m WHERE m.entry_id = e.festival_id)')
      ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

I think this code more readable and simple than others.