# Zend subquery arguments

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

The query below represents what I am trying to do, I need to pull in a list of blog_posts and also join with a users table.

What it is also doing is pulling in a random 'picture_filename' from blog_updates_pictures. It needs blog_updates as a join to reference the blog_update_id.

What I'd like to do now is also COUNT the number of blog_updates for each blog_post. I think this is a subquery but every implementation fails. It would also be good to have the count accept arguments (ie. blog_updates where date = ?). Also, there may be no updates or pictures to a blog_post.

```
$select = $db->select ();
$select->from ( array ('b' => 'blog_posts' ), array('headline', 'date_created'));
$select->join ( array ('u' => 'users' ), 'u.user_id = b.user_id', array ( 'email' ) );
$select->joinLeft ( array ('bu' => 'blog_updates' ), 'bu.blog_id = b.blog_id', array () );
$select->joinLeft ( array ('bup' => 'blog_updates_pictures' ), 'bu.blog_update_id = bup.blog_update_id', array ('picture_filename' ) );
```

Can someone show me the way?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer for how to create subquery using  Zend_Db_Select http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604872/nested-select-using-zend-db/5609246#5609246

Comment: put up a sample schema + data, and i'll put up a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like to do now is also COUNT the number of blog_updates for each blog_post.

You can achieve that using aggregation - use `GROUP BY bu.blog_id`, and as additional column `COUNT(bu.blog_id) AS blog_updates_count`. It should work.

Comment: That does work, but how can I then specify the date param? It will then only find blog_posts that do have updates ...

Comment: Code that I wrote will find also posts without updates. It depends on using LEFT or INNER JOIN, not on GROUP BY. Specyfing date? You can specify date param as normal WHERE date_created < [date].

Comment: Adding a where clause returns ONLY blog_posts with updates that are date_created <. I want it to return all blog_posts and updates to be null if they dont meet the search criteria.

Comment: Replace `GROUP BY bu.blog_id` with `GROUP BY b.blog_id`.

Comment: Yeah that is a correction but still where can I put the specification for updates over a certain date?

Comment: You're doing left join, so in join clause => `SELECT FROM table LEFT JOIN another_table ON table.at_id = another_table.id AND another_table.updated_at BETWEEN '2011-12-12 AND '2011-12-23'`

Answer (score 0):

Create subselects as:

```
$subselect = $db->select()
  ->from(
    array ('bu' => 'blog_updates' ),
    array(
      'blog_id', 
      'updates' => 'count(*)' 
    )
  )
  ->group("bu.blog_id");
```

And then join the $subselect with your main $select as:

```
$select->join(
  array( 't' => $subselect),
  "t.blog_id = b.blog_id",
  array( 'updates' )
);
```

If we had the table structure you might get a more complete answer