# Make query on a rowset of a previous query Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, rowset

I'd like to execute a MySQL query on a rowset that a zend select returned me from another query.

The reason is that I need the previous "more general" query and then need to get more precise rows depending on what I want from them.

Is there a way to do so to avoid making another request to the database ?

The long story is that I'm using an autocomplete plugin which returns me the infos about different cities matching the pattern that user input. This is a fastidious query to make and I'd like to avoid making it each time the user change some parameters to the query which don't concern the city in question.

So the autocomplete return me a rowset with multiple cities, and from that I'd like to 'eliminate' some of them which don't correspond to user options like a price range, distance etc.

I'd like to keep that rowset the longest as I can and execute some filtering to it instead of requesting directly a new rowset to the database every time.

Is there a way to execute MySQL queries on that rowset or do I have to convert it to an array and do 'manual' filtering on them ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for 'Nested Select'. In Zend_DB you can do it like in this post:

> [Nested Select using Zend Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604872/nested-select-using-zend-db)

If you've got Doctrine 1.x in your project, you can do this DQL query:

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
        $q->addComponent('m', 'Application_Model_Table')
        ->from('(SELECT * FROM table2 m2 WHERE ... // here is first query

        ) AS m') // IMPORTANT- name as m !
            ->orderBy('m.created ASC')
            ->limit($limit)
            ->where(' // connect tables or give 2\'nd where');
        return $q->execute();
```

I hope this is what you are looking for