# How to join a collection with a query in Magento

Tags: php, magento, collections, grid, export

I have a table represented in backend with two renderd fields, but when I try to make a csv export from this grid, those two fields are not included.

So I tried to make a join from the initial collection but I would have to make a join with a query / select like this:

```
SELECT main_table.*, art.artworks_uploaded
FROM mage_artist_details AS main_table
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT artist_id, COUNT(*) AS artworks_uploaded
FROM mage_art_works
GROUP BY artist_id
) AS art ON main_table.user_id = art.artist_id
```

Any ideeas of how can I obtain this?
If I try and use directly this query for my collection, I lose pagination in grid.

If I try and replace a table with a query in the next line I get errors:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('art' => 'mage_art_works'),'main_table.user_id = art.artist_id',array('artworks_uploaded' => 'COUNT(*)'))
```

Comment: Try to google 'Zend nested select'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727859/how-to-build-nested-select-on-zend-db