# Zend Framework select in select Zend_Db_Table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

does anyone know how to do a nested query such as "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,12) table ORDER BY rand ()", using Zend_Db_Table?

Comment: Maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340564/writing-a-subquery-using-zend-db

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in direct way. You can try some workarounds, but still the best way will be to get db adapter and query manually like:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,12) table ORDER BY rand ()');
```

If you want try workarounds like creating 2 queries and mixing them, passing subquery as ->from() part etc. have a look at this topic [Zend_Db_Table subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718888/zend-db-table-subquery)